# Spring Boot 2 Transactional Annotation Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, activemq-artemis, distributed-transactions

Question regarding our Spring Boot 2.3.8.RELEASE implementation of @Transactional. The requirement is to implement **distributed** transactions that writes to an instance of PostgreSQL and ActiveMQ Artemis queues. If one commit fails, then so should the other. We are using Atomikos for our JTA Transaction Manager.

I think I have implemented everything I need, but clearly not. When I throw an **Exception** in my **service** code to test the rollback functionality, it clearly does not work: The message is written to ActiveMQ Artemis even after I throw an **exception** in the **service** code.

Any help with diagnosing and fixing would be much appreciated. If any additional details are required, please let me know.

Please find the details of the implementation below:

**Spring Boot Application**:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import xxx.xxx.Users;
import xxx.xxx.TransactionServiceImpl;

@SpringBootApplication
(
        exclude = {
                    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                    JmsAutoConfiguration.class,
                    ActiveMQAutoConfiguration.class,
                    ArtemisAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
public class BApplication implements CommandLineRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //  SpringApplication.run(BoilerplateApplication.class, args);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(BApplication.class, args);
        System.in.read();
        ctx.close();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    TransactionServiceImpl tsi;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        Users user = new Users();
        user.setFirstName("Moe");
        user.setGender("M");
        user.setLastName("Moe");
        tsi.save(user);
    }
}
```

Here is the JTA Configuration:

**JTA Configuration**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionService;
import com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp;
import com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager;
import com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean;
import com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource;

@Configuration("jtaConfig")
public class JtaConfig
{
    private static final Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JtaConfig.class);

    @Value("${amq.broker.url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${amq.broker.username}")
    private String brokerUsername;

    @Value("${amq.broker.password}")
    private String brokerPassword;
    
    @Value("${postgresql.datasource.url}")
    String dataSourceUrl;

    @Value("${postgresql.datasource.username}")
    String dsUsername;

    @Value("${postgresql.datasource.password}")
    String dsPassword;

    @Value("${postgresql.datasource.driver.classname}")
    String dsClassName;
    
    @Value("${postgresql.initial.connections}")
    int initialDSConnections;
    
    @Value("${postgresql.max.connections}")
    int maxDSConnections;
    
    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "shutdownForce")
    public UserTransactionService userTransactionService()
    {
        Properties atProps = new Properties();
        atProps.put("com.atomikos.icatch.service", "com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory");
        return new UserTransactionServiceImp(atProps);
    }

    @Bean (initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    @DependsOn("userTransactionService")
    public UserTransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager()
    {
        UserTransactionManager utm = new UserTransactionManager();
        utm.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        utm.setForceShutdown(true);
        return utm;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("userTransactionService")
    public UserTransaction userTransaction()
    {
        UserTransactionImp ut = new UserTransactionImp();
        try
        {
            ut.setTransactionTimeout(1000);
        }
        catch (SystemException _e)
        {
            appLogger.error("Configuration exception.", _e);
            return null;
        }
        return ut;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter()
    {
        return new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    } 
    
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "pgDataSource1", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource pgDataSource1()
    {
        PGXADataSource primaryXaDataSource = new PGXADataSource();
        primaryXaDataSource.setUrl(dataSourceUrl);
        primaryXaDataSource.setUser(dsUsername);
        primaryXaDataSource.setPassword(dsPassword);

        AtomikosDataSourceBean xaDataSource = new AtomikosDataSourceBean();
        xaDataSource.setXaDataSource(primaryXaDataSource);
        xaDataSource.setUniqueResourceName("primaryXaDs1");
        xaDataSource.setMinPoolSize(initialDSConnections);
        xaDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(maxDSConnections);
        return xaDataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "jmsConnectionFactory", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory()
    {
        AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean atomikosConnectionFactoryBean = new AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean();
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMqXaConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(); 
        try
        {
            activeMqXaConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
            activeMqXaConnectionFactory.setUser(brokerUsername);
            activeMqXaConnectionFactory.setPassword(brokerPassword);
            atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setUniqueResourceName("jmsXAConnectionFactory");
            atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setLocalTransactionMode(false);
            atomikosConnectionFactoryBean.setXaConnectionFactory(activeMqXaConnectionFactory);
        }
        catch (JMSException _e)
        {
            appLogger.info("JMS Configuration Error: " + _e);
            _e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return atomikosConnectionFactoryBean;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructDetails()
    {
        appLogger.info("Post Construct Start: JtaConfig.");
        appLogger.info("  - JMS: Artemis URL: {}", brokerUrl);
        appLogger.info("  - Artemis Username: {}", brokerUsername);
        appLogger.info("  - Artemis Password: {}", brokerPassword);
        appLogger.info("  - DS: PostgreSQL URL: {}", dataSourceUrl);
        appLogger.info("  - DS: PostgreSQL Username: {}", dsUsername);
        appLogger.info("  - DS: PostgreSQL Password: {}", dsPassword);
        appLogger.info("  - DS: PostgreSQL Min Conn: {}", initialDSConnections);
        appLogger.info("  - DS: PostgreSQL Max Conn: {}", maxDSConnections);
        appLogger.info("Post Construct End: JtaConfig.");
        appLogger.info(" ");
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation for Services Configuration:

**Services Configuration**:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx.xxx.service")
public class ServicesConfig
{
    private Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServicesConfig.class);
    
    @Autowired
    JtaConfig jtaConfig;
    
    @Bean(name = "xaJmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate()
    {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jtaConfig.connectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(false);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "entityManangerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("xxx.xxx.model");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(jtaConfig.pgDataSource1());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jtaConfig.hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("entityManagerFactoryA");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jtaConfig.jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        JtaTransactionManager ptm = new JtaTransactionManager();
        ptm.setTransactionManager(jtaConfig.atomikosTransactionManager());
        ptm.setUserTransaction(jtaConfig.userTransaction());
        return ptm;
    }
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstructDetails()
    {
        appLogger.info("Post Construct Start: ServicesConfig.");
        appLogger.info("  - JMS: Artemis URL: {}", jtaConfig);
        appLogger.info("  - JMS Template: {}", jmsTemplate());
        appLogger.info("Post Construct End: ServicesConfig.");
        appLogger.info(" ");
    }
}
```

Here is the Service implementation:

**TransactionServiceImpl**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import xxx.xxx.Users;

@Service("transactionService")
@Transactional
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionServiceIntf
{
    private static final Logger appLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("xaJmsTemplate")
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Override
    public Users save(Users _user)
    {
        appLogger.info("TransactionServiceImpl: save: Entered.");
        Users user = _user;
        try
        {
            if(user == null)
            {
                appLogger.info("User: Null.");
            }
            else
            {
                if(jmsTemplate == null)
                {
                    appLogger.info("JMS Template: Null.");
                }
                else
                {
                    appLogger.info("JMS Template: Saving.");
                    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("crequests", user);
                }
            }
            // The rollback should happen with the exception.
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch(Exception _e)
        {
            appLogger.error("Catching exception: " + _e);
        }
        appLogger.info("TransactionServiceImpl: save: Exiting.");
        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to configure anything. Simply use the atomikos starter and it will work

Comment: I don't know what is atomikos, but I see that you are catching the exception, normally @Transactional will not rollback, if your method doesn't  throw exception.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Could you please elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: 1 Message Broker and 1 Database in a XA Transaction with Atomikos is supported out of the box without configuration. You just have to add the atomikos starter dependency in maven pom.xml

Comment: @YuvarajG: That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Will try that as well. Thank you.